# How to supress verbose output when calling sklearn scalers?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

In sci-kit learn Scaling mehtods => list = [StandardScaler(), RobustScaler()... ]

I want to save the file name for the loop iteration.

**df.to_csv("str(a)+.csv")
=> StandardSclaer().csv**

In popular, Jupyter and Colab are well-known IDE.

But I have a problem with the same code

below is the example.

1. In Jupyter

```
list4 = [StandardScaler()]

for i in list4 : 
    print(str(i))
```

output : `StandardScaler()`

2. In Colab

```
for i in list4 : 
    print(str(i))
```

Output : `StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)`

why does this happen?

I want to print like Jupyter (1) in Colab, how can I do it?

Comment: Are you sure the *versions* of scikit-learn are the same in the two cases? Please update your question with the respective versions (`import sklearn` and `sklearn.__version__`); in Colab it should be `0.22.2.post1`.

Comment: @desertnaut Oh.. I didn't notice that. It was different version. In jupyter 0.23.2 but colab was 0.22.2post1. It may be a difference between other versions.  Thank you

Comment: Just use `__class__.__name__` that should return the name of a class. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is a matter of Jupyter vs Colab or (most probably) with the scikit-learn version used; nevertheless, you can replace `str(i)` with `str(i).split('(')[0]` and get the result you want:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, RobustScaler
list4 = [StandardScaler(), RobustScaler()]
for i in list4 : 
    print(str(i).split('(')[0])
```

Result:

```
StandardScaler
RobustScaler
```

getting also rid of the unnecessary (for a file name) parentheses.

Notice that this will also work even in a different environment where the output of `str(i)` is `StandardScaler()` instead of the verbose version `StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)`:

```
print('StandardScaler()'.split('(')[0])
# result:
StandardScaler
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cls.__class__.__name__` to get the string name of a class:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, RobustScaler

scalers = [StandardScaler(), RobustScaler()]

for scaler in scalers: 
    print(scaler.__class__.__name__)

# Results
## StandardScaler
## RobustScaler
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `print()` inside colab gives you more information about how the StandardScaler was created. As I use Jupyterlab, the output is the same as in colab. I am not sure, what you need it for, but however, here an not so pretty solution if you need the same output:

```
obj = StandardScaler()
print(type(obj))
```

->

```
<class 'sklearn.preprocessing.data.StandardScaler'>
```